# Moving Classes into single directory [ant]

Tags: ant

So I need to create a custom build script for my java project but my java project currently is separated into packages. When finished my ant script needs to ftp and copy over the executable jar file and run it. But for know I am having trouble creating the runnable jar.

The problem is that my ant script will create directories based on my packages.

Directory Skeleton:

```
class:
quadcopter->QuadCopter.class 
quadcopter->PID->pid_server.class
quadcopter->PID->pid_client.class
```

It compiles fine and gives me all the classes. But when I run my ant to make the jar.

```
    <target name = "finish" depends="compile">
         <delete file = "${bone.jar}/quad.jar"/>
         <delete file = "MANIFEST.MF"/>
         <manifest file = "MANIFEST.MF">
              <attribute name = "Main-Class" value = "QuadCopter"/>
         <attribute name = "Class-Path" value = "."/>
         </manifest>
    <jar destfile = "${bone.jar}/quad.jar" basedir = "." includes = "${bone.class}/*.class" manifest = "MANIFEST.MF"/>
   </target>
```

The ant script does not go through all the directories and puts all the classes in the jar. Is there a way to put all the class files into one directory regardless of how many packages I have? Or is there a way to go through all the directories and add the class files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the jar tag add the following:

```
  <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
     <include name="**/*.class"/>
  </fileset>
```

where classes.dir is the output folder where the compile puts the classes.  This will write all the classes to the jar in their respective folders.